# iterate over map of filename=>content with for_each in resource

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I want to use a for_each in a kubernetes provider's kubernetes_config_map_v1's data section .. iterating over a map of filename=>content. I do not know how, as this does not work:

```
...
  files = {for filename in fileset(path.root, "test/*json"): filename => templatefile("${path.root}/${filename}", {
      prefix = local.prefix
    }
  )}
...

resource kubernetes_config_map_v1  xyz {
...
  data = {
    for_each = var.files
    each.key = each.value
  }
}
```

Error is: `The "each" object can be used only in "module" or "resource" blocks, and only when the "for_each" argument is set`

Any ideas?

Comment: 1. The first part of the snippet definitely cannot be assigned to `var.files` with that syntax, so please fill in the information gaps there. 2. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Comment: "does not work" - is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors?

Comment: for_each cannot be used like this, you should put that at the begging of the resource to create more than one of it. If you need more data block use a dynamic block, if you need a map with all keys and values use a locals block and build a local with `{for k,v in var.files : k => v}` and after use the local variable in resource

Comment: @MattSchuchard: yes it can?

Comment: @Marcin: it is in my post, see "Error is:"

Comment: @DaniloCacace: thanks, figured that out and came up with the solution, see below

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple, and does not need `for_each`:

```
resource kubernetes_config_map_v1  xyz {
...
  data = var.files
}
```